# Interior Product of the normal with the volumeform on the euclidean sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, fixed-point-theorems, stokes-theorem

Let $n:S^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be the outer normal $n(x)=x$, and $\alpha:=n\lrcorner (dx_1\wedge \dots dx_n)$ a $(n-1)$-form on $S^{n-1}$.

I want to proof that $\int_{S^{n-1}} \alpha >0$.

It is a step in a proof of Brouwer's fixed point theorem with differential function and with the use of Stokes theorem. All is really logical, i just cant see why that form is a positive meassure, in particular why the integral over the sphere is bigger than 0. Would appreciate any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: As you defined $n$, it makes sense on all of $\mathbb R^n$ and inserting this into $dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$ you get an extension of $\alpha$ to a $(n-1)$-form defined on all of $\mathbb R^n$. Then you can apply Stokes to compute your integral as the integral of $d\alpha$ over the unit ball. But $d\alpha$ can be easily computed directly.

Comment: $d\alpha$ should be 0 since it would be $n$-form on a $n-1$ dimensional area. I dont see how that would help me for the computation of $\int \alpha$

Comment: Ah, do you mean
$\int_S \alpha=\int_D d\alpha = \int_D d(dx^1\dots dx^n)(x)=\int_D d(x_1 dx^2 \dots dx^n)=\int_D dx^1\dots dx^n=vol(D)> 0 $

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean (up to a factor of $n$ that you are missing).

Answer (score 1):

$dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$ is a (positive) volume n-form of the ambient space which induces a (positive) volume $(n-1)$-form on $S^{n-1}$ using its unit normal vector field $\nu$, $\alpha:=\nu\lrcorner (dx_1\wedge \dots dx_n)$ and the volume (the hyper-surface "area") of the sphere is $\int_{S^{n-1}} \alpha > 0$.